# Same projection but wrong extent using QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, extents

How can I change the extent of a shp?

I have three layers, all reprojected properly from the original projection, however, the layers do not align due to different extents. If I try to change extent by Export - Save as ... I get an empty shp.

Comment: If data which should overlay does not then there was an error in the transformation lineage. You don't want to change the extents, you want the data correctly projected.

Comment: Thank you. How can I ensure correct transformation besides using the Save as or Reproject layer function?

Comment: Do the original layers allign? If they do and you save/export or use reproject layer function, everything should be OK. If not, add more Information (edit the initial post).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What kind of information would help?